# Django Images Display

Tags: python, django, url

Ok, now I know how to display images on ONE /myurl/ in Django as a list (YEAH!)

But how can I display ONE Image per url with a button to click to the next image etc.

So basically I would want to come to the first /urlstart/:

text and a next button.

brings user to e.g. /urlstart/1

There the first image of a List is displayed and below that a button.

That brings user to /urlstart/2

Here the next image of a list is displayed.

etc.

How does the url.py regex part have to look like so this is possible?
How does the view has to be tweaked to get 1 List of Images but multiple urls?

And finally if anybody has implemented this with a down loadable and installable module/library, like e.g. photologue (which unfortunately did not work for me) or any better idea than that I would be really happy to get some insights on how to make this fast and efficient.

Thanks so much to everybody who takes the time to answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL regex could look something like this:

```
url(r'^urlstart/(?P<image_id>\d*)/?$', 'urlstart', name='urlstart')
```

View code could look something like this:

```
def urlstart(request, image_id=0):
  if image_id == 0:
    image = None
  else:
    image = get_object_or_404(Image, image_id)
  next_image = image_id + 1

  return render_to_response('template.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

Template code:

```
{% if image %}
  <img src={{ image.url }}>
  <a href="/urlstart/{{ next_image }}">Next</a>
{% else %}
  Put your text here.  See first image by clicking <a href="/urlstart/1">here</a>
{% endif %}
```

Obviously this is simplified.  For example, you may want to check to see if there is an image to come next.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should use {% url %} template tag to avoid hard coding urls in your templates.

Comment: Thanks a million. This is fantastic, I will try immediately. One question right now. The regex part (?P<image_id>\d*)/?$ has to be changed to fit or if I use your code below it will work?

Comment: Another question where do I mention where my pictures are located on the harddrive?

Comment: So I tried and 2 things I dont understand/wont work:

1. Where do i store the images so Django can read them in? Do I name them 0.jpg, 1.gif, 2.png etc to get the image_id right?

2. The regex part: you have "url" at the start. I never saw any regex like this. Usually they start with a "(". And even though I get an error, it seems the regexs are correct like that. What does the url at the start exactly mean?

Comment: MacPython,

Take a look at the Django documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/

Particularly, look at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-urls for URLs.

Comment: Also, you can call the image whatever you like.  Create a django model that includes an ImageField.  See the docs on uploaded files for more info (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#topics-http-file-uploads)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Pagination](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) which will provide you with Next/Previous links, etc.

Also, it would probably be a good idea to use [permalinks](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator) and pass the next/previous image in from the view instead of hard-coding the URL into the template.