# Displaying image url from django template

Tags: html, django, django-templates

this is a really basic question -

I have a model called Book, which has an attribute imageURL (which is a charfield).

I have this template code -

```
<text class= "text" id = "bookTitle">{{ book.title|safe }}</text><br/>
                <text class= "text" id= "bookAuthor">by {{ book.author|safe }}</text><br/>
                <img src= str(book.imageURL) class = "result" />
```

However, the str(book.imageURL) always returns an unicode value (because that's what Django models do?) - how can I get the string url so I can put it in here?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266048/django-images-display


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901551/how-do-i-include-image-files-in-django-templates

Comment: try this: <img src="{{ book.imageURL }}" class="result" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template code is invalid, try this:

```
<text class= "text" id = "bookTitle">{{ book.title|safe }}</text><br/>
                <text class= "text" id= "bookAuthor">by {{ book.author|safe }}</text><br/>
                <img src="{{ book.imageURL }}" class = "result" />
```